# Flutter Table Calendar : Load Event From Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Table Calendar but the event load from firestore did not show on Table Calendar(For now it only show a list of event without filtering the date). **How can I show to user when they click at the selected date, it will show event for that particular date?**

[image]

Image above is the result.

[image]
Image above is my firestore

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: _firestore.collection('planning').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Center(
          child: Text('Loading'),
        );
      }

      var docs = snapshot.data.docs;

      List<Detail> dataWidgets = [];

      var event;
      var selectedDate;

      for(var data in docs){
        selectedDate = data.data()['selectedDate'];
        final wpEventController = data.data()['wpEventController'];
        event = data.data()['event'];
        final detailWp = data.data()['detailWp'];
        final name = data.data()['name'];
        final selectedEvent = data.data()['selectedEvent'];

        final dataWidget = Detail(selectedDate: selectedDate,wpEventController: wpEventController,event: event,detailWP: detailWp,name: name,selectedEvent:selectedEvent);
        dataWidgets.add(dataWidget);

      }

      print(event);
```

Above is my StreamBuilder,

> I/flutter (16094): {date: Timestamp(seconds=1678363200, nanoseconds=0), event: [test]}

Above is the print of the event.

```
TableCalendar(
              onDaySelected: (date, events, holiday){
                setState((){
                  _selectedEvent = events;
                });
              },
              events: _events,
              calendarController: _calendarController,
              startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
              headerStyle: HeaderStyle(formatButtonShowsNext: false),
              calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                  selectedColor: Colors.red[900], todayColor: Colors.red),
            ),
```

Above is my Table Calendar.

The event in Table Calendar required a `Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>>`.

```
Map <DateTime,List<dynamic>>_events;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Displaying events on selected date you need to convert `event` to your suggested Type `Map <DateTime,List<dynamic>> _events;` But I will recommend you to use `Map <DateTime,List<Detail>> _events;` here because this will help with data Modeling.

Here’s what I have tested and worked :

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('planning').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('Loading'),
      );
    }

    var docs = snapshot.data.docs;

    Map<DateTime, List<Detail>> events = {};

    for (var data in docs) {
      var eventDate = (data.data()['date'] as Timestamp).toDate();
      var eventData = data.data()['event'];
      var selectedDate = data.data()['selectedDate'];
      var name = data.data()['name'];
      var selectedEvent = data.data()['selectedEvent'];
      var detailWp = data.data()['detailWp'];
      var wpEventController = data.data()['wpEventController'];

      if (events[eventDate] == null) {
        events[eventDate] = [];
      }

      var yourData = Detail(
        date: eventDate,
        event: eventData,
        selectedDate: selectedDate,
        name: name,
        selectedEvent: selectedEvent,
        detailWp: detailWp,
        wpEventController: wpEventController,
      );

      events[eventDate].add(yourData);
    }

    return TableCalendar(
      events: events.map(
        (key, value) => MapEntry(
          key,
          value.map((data) => data.event).toList(),
        ),
      ),
      calendarController: _calendarController,
      onDaySelected: (date, events, holidays) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedEvents = events.map((event) => event as Detail).toList();
        });
      },
      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
      headerStyle: HeaderStyle(formatButtonShowsNext: false),
      calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
        selectedColor: Colors.red[900],
        todayColor: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

I have used `map` to convert the `Detail` object to the event field. If we use `Map <DateTime,List<Detail>>` type over `Map <DateTime,List<dynamic>>` we will get autocomplete with benefits of transforming data into Model structure to get type safety.

Reference taken from : [**`Filter list by calendar`**](https://community.flutterflow.io/c/discuss-and-get-help/filter-list-by-calendar), [**`Table Calendar`**](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar)

Comment: how do you test it? and it worked? I don't get it. what is YourDataModel? what is eventDate and eventData? may you make it clear.. I have another screen to add the event for the calendar which contain textformfield. can you show me complete code? with the dataModel.

Comment: It only show marker to the table calendar to indicate has event for that particular date, how to show event list at the bottom of the calendar? I mean a list of event? @Rohit